# Assistance With Lex/Flex Pattern

Tags: lex

The prof. for my C/C++ class has introduced us to Flex (lexicographical analyzer), so this means I am total green-horn in the use of flex.

The homework assignment I am working on currently is to remove the html tags from a simple html file, leaving only the content. With the statement:

```
[^\/\n<>"]*   printf("%s\n", yytext);
```

I am able to remove the angle and the quotation marks  but it leaves behind the tag text. I then added   a-z inside the angle brackets and according to one web tutorial placing quotation marks around the angle brackets makes that a pattern:

```
[^\/\n"< a-zA-Z>""]*   printf("%s\n", yytext);
```

All this did was to remove all the letters leaving behind only numbers an punctuation, which is not what I was after.

So how can I tell flex to include the text between the angle brackets along with the brackets to make a single regexp class out of it? A small block of instruction would preferred to just be given the answer. This is cool utility that I intend to learn and use.

Thanks in advance
Walt

Answer (score 1):

well, html tags all look like `<something with optional modifiers>` (AFAIK), so I'd look for a rule set like

```
<[^>]*> { /* skip */ }
.       { printf("\%s", yytext); }
```

Of course you can speed up processing if you try to eat everything that is no html tag at once. But the rule set above should work and is easy to understand.

Comment: If you don't want to use `ECHO`, then `fputc(yytext[0], yyout);` is more accurate (uses `yyout` instead of `stdout`) and a lot less overhead.

Comment: @rici you're right, that's a good optimization. It'll probably speed up the scanning by a factor. I didn't think of it as my actions (as well as my re) aren't that simple most of the time.

Comment: `printf` is used waaay too often. Many times, `fputc` and `fputs` would be faster -- and safer, in the case of people too lazy to write a format string. But then, if you don't need a format string, why not just use `fputs`? By the way, you wanted `()` instead of `{}` and C doesn't require (or, technically, allow) backslash-escaped percent.

Comment: @rici thank you for pointing at the syntax error. I corrected it. I left the printf in order to keep your valuable comments valid.